# How to enable Oracle-Managed Files on Oracle Express for Windows XP

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I'm trying to enable Oracle-Managed Files on Oracle Express for Windows XP.

From everything I've read, I need to set `db_create_file_dest` to an existing directory in the file system.

I've tried setting `db_create_file_dest=C:\somedir` in `init.ora`. There appears to be two `init.ora` files, so I added it to both:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\config\scripts\init.ora
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\dbs\init.ora
```

After restarting the Oracle service (I also tried rebooting Windows), 
`db_create_file_dest` is still not set. It would appear that Oracle is not using either `init.ora` files.

How do I go about setting `db_create_file_dest` and thereby enabling Oracle-Managed Files?

I am running Oracle Database 11g Express Edition on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle uses two different types of init files.

1. pfile (text)
2. spfile (binary)

You changed pfile. But you may need to change spfile. [Find](http://www.orafaq.com/node/5) if you are using spfile

```
SELECT DECODE(value, NULL, 'PFILE', 'SPFILE') "Init File Type" 
   FROM sys.v_$parameter WHERE name = 'spfile';
```

if you are using spfile change this parameter using sql.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET db_create_file_dest=..... SCOPE=BOTH
```